# Row count from stored procedure that has a nested insert exec and has temp tables dropped at the end?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How to get row count from stored procedure that has a nested insert exec and has temp tables dropped at the end?

I know your first thought is "this is a duplicate question". But bear with me. All the other related questions have answers that do not work for my particular situation. Allow me to explain why with the following conditions.

1. I **cannot** edit the stored procedure for work related reasons.
2. Inserting the results into a temp table doesn't work because of the "An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested" error.
3. Trying to use `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` immediately after the EXEC statement doesn't work for me because the stored procedure ends with temp tables being dropped, so the result value is always 0.

Here are some sample "solutions" from other related question, but none work because of the previous listed conditions, or should I rather say restrictions.

This returns 0: the results with those parameters actually has 17 records.

```
EXEC FCXSch.AppFcxConsultarCreditoPorRenovarSel -1, -1, 63, -1,  'OGR', 350
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS NumRows
```

And this returns an error "An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested":

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(SomeColumns INT)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
    EXEC FCXSch.AppFcxConsultarCreditoPorRenovarSel -1, -1, 63, -1,  'OGR', 350
```

Comment: Given those constraints it's not possible _*happy to be proven wrong_

Comment: Things are looking a bit grim! Too bad you can't edit the stored procedure, huh?

Comment: "I cannot edit the stored procedure for work related reasons." - that's too poor a reason to take seriously...